# Solutions for tracking cucumber features and scenarios?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am looking for good solutions for tracking and organizing cucumber features and scenarios. I need something that can be remotely accessible for customers and developers. Something hosted would be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/) is based on user stories, so it should probably fit your needs --and then some more.

Answer (score 0):

[Lowdown](http://lowdownapp.com/) looks interesting, although it's very early days. They're participating in the 2009 Rails Rumble. Pivotal Tracker is also very slick, although it's not tied in to Cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

For sharing features between customers and developers, I really like [Relish](https://www.relishapp.com/). To get a good idea of what an active project looks like, check out the Features for [RSpec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec).